# How to set reCaptcha 3.0 threshold

Tags: recaptcha, grecaptcha

I am using the enterprise edition of google reCaptcha and trying to figure out how to set the threshold via the admin interface. Is it possible or is it a must to do this via code when I get the captcha verification response?

I have looked all over Google docs and this part isn’t clear. I can see a captcha recommendation part where I can simulate but not actual setting. Please help. Thanks in advance.